# the dictionary requires a model item of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I have tried adding `IEnumerable` class in my view, but still doesnt work, I also tried changing `.ToList()` to `To.String()` gave me another error, didnt add another method but still complained about `IEnumebable` server error

my controller:

```
namespace Questionnaire.Controllers
{
  public class QuestionnaireController : Controller
    {
      QUESTIONNAREDataContext questions = new QUESTIONNAREDataContext();
       public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var selectQuestion = (from q in questions.QUESTIONTABLEs
                                 select q).ToList();
            return View(selectQuestion);
        }

    }
}
```

my model:

```
namespace Questionnaire.Models
{
    public class QuestionModels
    {
        [Display(Name="Questions Types")]
        public string Question { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my view:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Questionnaire.Models.QuestionModels>
    <div>
        @foreach (var questionItem in Model)
        {
            //questionItem.Question;
            @questionItem.Question
        }

    </div>
```

Comment: Well what is the type of `questions.QUESTIONTABLEs`? (And why are you using a LINQ query that does nothing? You might as well just use `questions.QUESTIONTABLEs.ToList()`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your Model Type:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Questionnaire.Models.QuestionModels>
```

So in your controller, you should do this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var selectQuestion = (from q in questions.QUESTIONTABLEs
                                 select new QuestionModels{ /*... */}).ToList();
            return View(selectQuestion);
        }
```